# Weird behavior C#

Tags: c#

Somehow I'm getting a weird result from a GetString(). So, in my project I got this code:

```
byte[] arrayBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(n["spo_fdat"].InnerText);
string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arrayBytes);
```

The InnerText Value and the code is in: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mMUlti

So, my problem is that somehow I'm getting this result on my Visual Studio:

[image]

While in the online compiler that I post above the output is as expected.
This output is an output for a printer and this \0 are destroying the format.

Anyone have a clue of what is going on and what should I do/try?

Comment: Try `string str = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(arrayBytes);`

Comment: So, the problem is you can't see the correct string while debugging? Or do you get wrong output unless you use the online compiler?

Comment: I get the same "garbage" in dotnetfiddle as you have in your test results listed here.

Comment: So I can't see your image or fiddle here (firewall issues), but my first guess is that the array of bytes isn't in UTF-8 encoding.  It could be UTF-16 (default for C# strings), or whatever the control you are reading from defaults to.

Comment: Well, I think the issue is with the input. Are you not missing some characters?

Comment: @JohnWu It worked better but some data was lost.

Comment: @enkryptor I'm sending the output to a file too and to the printer and it don't come was intended or as in the online compiler.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch It's, it was made by me co-worker.

Comment: @tgz nop, they are all there, otherwise the online compiler would not be correct.

Comment: Your byte array starts as follows: `239,0,187,0,191,0,16,0,67`. This 239,187,191 is the UTF8 byte order marker - the fact that you have null bytes between them makes me think that your input has been messed up in some way. How sure are you of the input? I should note that the following byte 16 is not one I'd expect in a text file (its data link escape) or does that make sense for you?

Comment: I've just noticed you've said its output designed for a printer. I'm no expert in such things but in fact stripping out every other byte looks like it might give you a legit file: `CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR2,2~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ` - does that look plausible?

Comment: @Chris Yes, I tried to replace the \0 but If I do some data get lost, I got the barcode but not the attached data. My Co-worker just noticed she encoded the data as default, it might be the problem.
Edit: Same behavior

Comment: Please define what it means that "the online compiler is correct".

Comment: @tgz If I paste the output from the online compiler in here: http://labelary.com/viewer.html it give me the right barcode with all the information in it. And its a copy paste from my project to the online compiler.

Comment: Why not try base64 encoding the online compiler output with an online encoder and compare it to the one in your snippet. I'm pretty sure it's an issue with the input.

Comment: The reason the online one looks correct (though I'm assuming the opening three unprintable characters are not right?) is likely because it doesn't render the null characters (`\0` in your debug string) so you're just seeing all the non-null stuff. I've suggested a way in my answer to remove all the odd numbered bytes (which are all null) and it seems to then produce the right output (that is it looks at a glance superficially similar to what I see on the output of the online one you said looks right).

Comment: @JoãoSilva Could you please go ahead and edit your question with specifics of what bytes you expect and what bytes you get? The fact that you copy something from a console reinterpreted in browser and it somehow works in some other tab in your browser is truly insufficient. Attempting to reinterpret a non-human-readable text that got incorrectly encoded is truly painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like for some reason every other byte in your input is null. If you strip those out you get something that looks much more plausible as printer commands (though I am no expert). Hopefully you can verify things...

To do this all I did was added this line in:

```
arrayBytes = arrayBytes.Where((x,i)=>i%2==0).ToArray();
```

The where command takes the value (x), and index (i) and if the index mode 2 is 0 (ie its even) then the where clause allows it - if its odd it throws it away.

The output I get from this starts:

```
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR2,2~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW607
^LL0406
```

There are some non-printing character in there too that look like possible printing commands (eg 16 is the first character that is "data link escape" character.

**Edited afterthought:**

The problem you have here is obviously a problem with the specification. It seems to be that your input is wrong. You need to talk to whoever generated it find out the specification they are using to generate it, make sure their ode matches that spec and then right your code to accept that spec. With a solid specification you should both be writing compatible code.

Comment: I have tried it but it didn't work, the replace \0 gave a better result but neither of them worked as intended. About the my input, if the input was wrong how it's working well in the online compiler? If I copy the output from https://dotnetfiddle.net/mMUlti and paste in http://labelary.com/viewer.html it would give me the correct output

Comment: @JoãoSilva: I'm confused then - running my above code modification my output looks identical to what I see in the online one except the online one has three unknown glyphs at the start as well as the box which I assume represents the data link escape character I mentioned. If I paste the output into the label thing it gives me a barcode with A2.1 and some other text underneath. What are you getting as output after my modification that is different from what you are seeing online?

Comment: what I'm getting from visual studio doesn't have after the A2.1 the text "Arm Piso Rua Predio Andar" while in the online compiler it have...

Comment: Well I'm getting that when I run my modified code either on my computer or on dotnetfiddle and then run them through labelary as you suggested. It sounds like you have more bugs that you need to hunt down. As far as I can tell the code modification I have suggested gives the output that you want. Have you checked the string as it is generated in VS after this code to see if it is what you want? Have you checked your input is the same (eg if you hardcode the base64 string as in your demo code does it work then)? Could you be losing data when you are trying to transmit because of that code?

Comment: Well, I have to check again the input question tomorrow with my co-worker since it comes from a webservice and I'm just consuming it. I just feel it's kinda weird to get this behavior.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/H3njC1d.png is my test output. And yes, it is weird. Your co-worker should tell you exactly what format you are expecting rather than leaving you guessing. Its not base64 encoded utf8 and if it should be then they have screwed up. If its not meant to be then you should have them tell you what it is. The problem with it missing off the other stuff? That's not weird, that's just bugs. Track them down by looking carefully at what comes in and out of each part of your code and see if its what you expect.

Comment: Also https://pasteboard.co/H3njC1d.png is my test output in labelary. As you can see works as you want.

Comment: I just notice that there was a \n that I wasn't removing when using your code... it worked for now! I will use it while I don't find a better solution and while I don't check that input question...
Thank you a lot Chris! that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try inspecting the bytes instead. You'll see that what you have encoded in the base-64 string is much closer to what Visual Studio shows to you in comparison to the output from dotnetfiddle. Consoles usually don't escape non-printables (such as `\0` - the `null` character) whereas Visual Studio string inspector does so in attempt to provide as much value to its user as possible.

Looking at your base-64 encoded data, it looks way more like UTF-16 than UTF-8. If you decode it like so, you'll perhaps get rid of the `null` characters in Visual Studio inspector as well.

Regardless of that, the base-64 data don't make much sense. More semantical context is required to figure out what the issue is.

According to inspection by Chris, it looks like the data is UTF-8 encoded in UTF-16.

You should be able to get proper results with the following:

```
var xml = //your base-64 input...
var arrayBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(xml);
var utf16 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(arrayBytes);
var utf8Bytes = utf16.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();
var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);

Console.WriteLine(utf8);
```

The opposite is probably how your input was created. However, you could also go for Chris' solution of ignoring every odd byte as it is basically the same with less weird encoding things going on (although this may be more explicit to what really goes on: UTF-8 inside UTF-16).

Comment: In the ArrayByte there are some bytes and then a 0, every odd index got a 0.

Comment: That means every odd byte is zero. That is usually the case when you have ASCII letters encoded in UTF-16 as the first byte is occupied by the ascii data and the second byte is empty.

Comment: I know its weird... But I can't find why it's happening... If I replace a the \0 for "" part of it work but some of the information get lost somehow.